# JetBrains (Android Studio/CLion) code fold region - switch back to ONLY fold the top level?

Tags: android-studio, ide, clion, jetbrains-ide, code-folding

In some recent version of Android Studio/CLion they changed the way the code folding works.

Previously <kbd>Cmd + Shift + '-'</kbd> would collapse only the toplevel region of code, such that if you clicked the folded region of code it would expand everything under it. Now you have to click into that code block and press <kbd>Cmd + Alt+ '+'</kbd> to expand all nested folds.

Is there a way I can switch back to the previous version of folding? That is it doesn't collapse if/else/{}blocks/etc? I've dug through the settings and docs and feel like I must be missing something.

Collapsed code (<kbd>Cmd + Shift + '-'</kbd>)
[image: collapsed code]

When you mouse click on a top level collapsed code block now (note line 36/55):
[image]

What I want to happen (What used to happen) when you clicked a top level code block:
[image]

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167045 I guess. Or find a better one: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=folding%20%22collapse%20all%22 P.S. If you do not mind using mouse: Clicking on `+` marker while holding `Alt` will apply that to all children nodes (so will expand/collapse ALL there). Other than that: did you know that Expand All works with selection if it's present?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I've been using those workarounds sporadically (though I hadn't found that issue, I will watch it), I just had a flow of browsing through files rapidly and my muscle memory of 5ish years is really hard to break.